# JQuery add class on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I use this code to add a class on scroll. The active class works great, but the location on the page when the class is placed is not correct. We use a main header on our website with position fixed and when this header becomes sticky it is places below our main header also with position fixed. The active class needs to be placed earlier on the page, because the content of that section already started, when the class is placed.

HTML:

```
    <div style="height:57px;">
    <div class="menu-header-product">
    <div class="product-anchor-links-wrapper">
    <nav class="product-page-nav">
        <ul class="menu-header-top-product">
            <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#description" class="product-nav-link">Productbeschrijving</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#additional" class="product-nav-link">Specificaties</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#reviews" class="product-nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="content">  
<section id="description">
<div class="box-description"></div>
</section>

<section id="additional">
<div class="box-additional"></div>
</section>

<section id="reviews">
<div class="box-reviews"></div>
</section>
</div>
```

What is wrong with this code:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 645) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.content'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 645) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-130 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
             }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('nav a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please post your html as well. or better yet, create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I edit my post with HTML.

Comment: and css too please. i want to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just noticed that your closing `</section>` tags are missing.

Comment: Damn it! Thanks Matthias, I just forgot to close </section>! Problem solved :)

Comment: Glad that helped, and good that you posted your HTML :)

Comment: @matthias_h you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot the closing `</section>` tags in your markup:

```
<section id="description">
 <div class="box-description"></div>
<section id="additional">
 <div class="box-additional"></div>
<section id="reviews">
 <div class="box-reviews"></div>
```

should be

```
<section id="description">
 <div class="box-description"></div>
</section>
<section id="additional">
 <div class="box-additional"></div>
</section>
<section id="reviews">
 <div class="box-reviews"></div>
</section>
```